# Get full path to file from argument

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am writing a shell script, and I am fairly new to it, but when the script gets run, the first first/second argument (depending on how you look at it) will be the file to load and execute. My question is, how would I get the location of the file based on where what directory `myscript` is run in?

```
myscript path/to/file.ext
myscript file.ext
myscript ../../file.ext
```

Basically I would like to get the path to the file that was passed in. How can that be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This snippet will get you the **full path** of your script and any arguments:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$i" )" && pwd )"
```

Replace `$i` with `$0` to get the full path of your script (`myscript`). `$1`, `$2`, ... will get you the full paths of subsequence arguments.

Comment: I feel like this fails for paths with relative paths with preceding parent directories, e.g. `../<path>`. If I'm in `/home/dir1/`, then typing in `(cd "$(dirname "../dir2/")" && pwd)` returns `/home/` instead of `/home/dir2/`.

Comment: UPDATE: Nevermind Tuan, you are correct. I wasn't adding the required file name in my path when I was testing this, I was only testing directories alone.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to use `realpath "$1"`. Despite being *intended* for use with symbolic links, it turns out that it works better than most other approaches for the *general* problem of making paths absolute.

On many systems, `realpath` might not be installed by default. Sometimes it is in its own package, sometimes it is in `coreutils`, etc.

Btw, this sort of question might be better suited on https://unix.stackexchange.com even though it's not off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks, I usually script this myself, but good to learn about this tool

Answer (score 5):

In bash:

```
pathToFile=$(dirname $1)
fileName=$(basename $1)
scriptPath=$(dirname $0)
scriptName=$(basename $0)
currentPath=$(pwd)
```

In other shell, you can try to repalce $( and ) with ` (back quote)

Comment: This will help me get the file basename which I will need too